# Can a Runesmith make more than one Permanent Rune?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, class-feature

Can my Runesmith use his Permanent Rune ability to make more than one Spell Permanent?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a quick [tour] to see how we work. We require multiple questions to be posted separately, for several reasons, but foremost of which is so that each problem gets the dedicated attention it deserves. I've edited this to remove the second "if not" question, which you can post as a separate question either now, or later depending on whether this question is answered 'yes' or 'no'. The removed parts are permanently stored in the edit history if you need to copy-and-paste them, which you can access by clicking the "edited [time] ago" note at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 8):

## No

> A 5th-level runesmith knows the secret of inscribing **a** permanent rune of a **single chosen spell** into his flesh.

Also, Permanent Rune does not mean you continuously benefit from the spell’s effect, it just means you can cast the spell twice per day as a spell-like ability. Not awful by any means, but not particularly exciting.

Comment: > *but not particularly exciting* That depends on how one interprets XP and GP costs, which are only paid at rune's inscribing. Casting, say, Limited Wish 2/day with no cost (or even Wish, if you have 10-level slot to sacrifice) could be sort of exciting.